# Setting difficulty not working

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am making a simple java text game in eclipse luna. Scanner.next() is not working. When I run it, after I ask for the user input, an error displays (java.util.NoSuchElementException). Have I just done something really dumb?

```
    while(whle) {
        System.out.print("Where do you want to go? Enter gym, store, or mountain. ");
        loc = goTo.next();
        loc = loc.toLowerCase();
        if(loc.equals("gym") || loc.equals("store") || loc.equals("mountain")) whle = false;
        else {
            System.out.println("Please enter an option. ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Everything is defined, and no errors pop up in the actual program, just when I run it.

Comment: Use another `Scanner#next` to consume the end of line character(s).

Comment: @Luiggi Mendozaif you mean `loc = goTo.next(); loc = goTo.next()` I tried and the same thing popped up

Comment: I mean `loc = goTo.next(); goTo.next();`

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza no, doesn't work

Comment: How do you initialize `goTo`?

Comment: Yes, please show more code, especially where you set up the Scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have your scanner initialized correctly like this

```
Scanner loc = new Scanner(System.in); //very important
```

And you have imported this class

```
import java.util.Scanner; //in the begining of the source code
```

it should work (other than that I think its a problem with your IDE, java version)

If that doesn't help, I ran it with this program by itself (with `boolean whle` initialized, `main` method and such) and it produces what I believe is what you want.

```
while(whle) {
    System.out.print("Where do you want to go? Enter gym, store, or mountain. ");
    String locstring= loc.next();
    if(locstring.equalsIgnoreCase("gym") || locstring.equalsIgnoreCase("store") || locstring.equalsIgnoreCase("mountain")){ whle = false;}
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter an option. ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any improvement to the code except for surrounding `whle = false;` with braces.

Comment: i cant tell if "goTo" is a scanner or not so I give Him/her a correct example of scanner

Comment: Again, I don't see any improvement to the code whatsoever. If the main purpose of your answer is showing how to initialize `Scanner loc`, then focus on that rather than saying *change your code  to `<same code posted by OP>`* when there's nothing to change.